# Is it possible to run Mac `Instruments` tools without having XCode installed?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, profiling, osx-elcapitan

I need to use the `Mac` *time-profiler* tool on `El-Capitan`. This tool comes with the `Instruments` package that comes with `XCode`.
Since `XCode` is a relatively big setup (in my case - `XCode-7` for `El-Capitan`) and since the targeted `Mac` is not a developer machine but rather a QA machine I would like to avoid installing `XCode`.
Does anybody know if it is possible to to run this profiler tool without having `XCode` installed?
Thanks for any information

Comment: Can't you just copy it from a dev machine and try?

Comment: (I should have mantioned it) I did copy the 'Instruments.app' from other El-Capitan machine and tried to run it, but received the following error: 'Instruments cannot be opened because of problem'...